# Java DateTime 12 hour format

Tags: java, date, time

I've got problem with passing date and time (12 hour format) in my LocalDateTime object.
Here's what I've done:

```
LocalDateTime MyDate;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a");
    MyDate.parse(date_frome_string, formatter)
```

When I'm trying to past text like:

```
2020-09-04 09:15 PM
```

I've got following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-09-04 09:15 PM' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field AmPmOfDay 0 differs from AmPmOfDay 1 derived from 09:15
```

When I'm passing:

```
2020-09-04 09:15 AM
```

It's all ok.

Comment: You're going to get this fixed, but also — your code should be prepared to handle `DateTimeParseException` and possibly _retry_ parsing with other formats because, while you are pasting what you want, people _**will**_ try to enter other formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The format symbol `HH` explicitly means 24-hour time.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) Use `hh` instead for 12-hour time.